# Benefits Of Multithreading In An Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm working on a long running process using Durable Functions. We don't process a huge number of requests, but when we do receive a request, it often takes five or more minutes for execution to complete.

I'm trying to shave down the time needed for larger inputs but splitting the work up into sections that can be completed in parallel by creating a `List<Task>` and then waiting for completion with `Task.WaitAll`.

In testing- I notice that while my code does work fine, I'm not seeing the performance gains that one would expect from breaking a task into N many parallel chunks, as opposed to completing them in a linear fashion.

With all of that in mind, my question regarding these unexpected results is this-

Do Azure Function host VMs have access to more than one core? I.E. can I count on multithreading to speed up CPU bound tasks- or is this parallelization only going to yield more context switching due to a lack of available cores?

Comment: What exactly are you doing that's taking so long ? Is it inherently parallelizable (can you post example code?) To answer your question, yes you can configure more cores but this depends on your type of plan - see https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

Comment: I think your approach of doing everything through multiple threads isn't making best use of Azure functions - consider using the Fan-Out-Fan-In approach (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/durable-functions-patterns-fan-out-and-fan-in/) so you don't need to concern yourself with multiple cores etc and let the Azure runtime scale things automatically

Comment: @auburg We take in JSON files or variable size and essentially map the underlying data onto a new JSON schema. Unfortunately I can't share code because it's for work, but I can say that the JSON is split into chunks that can be operated on independently. The number of independent chunks varies from input to input, but we should be seeing a performance gain in some of the really large outlier requests.

Comment: @auburg using the fan out pattern was/is my fallback plan in this case. I figured I should try multithreading first since the approach requires less refactoring. We've tried it before and the issue (according to my coworker anyway) was that the additional activity functions added undue overhead for smaller inputs. I'm thinking we could go with an approach where we only use the fan out pattern for larger inputs though- that could avoid the overhead issue.

Comment: when you say 'it takes four five minutes for execution to complete' what part of the json processing is taking up most of that time - is this some particularly CPU intensive task or are you doing some external database operations (for example) ?

Comment: @auburg We essentially break the entire process into two large steps. The first is to make an API call to pull down the JSON file from Azure Storage and deserialize it to our models, the second is to make modifications to the deserialized JSON. My focus right now is on that second part. There are a few very minimal IO operations that take place at the very end to store the modified JSON, not enough to have any significant impact on the execution time. In any event, this chunk of the process would be CPU bound, not IO bound.